# gps module stops outputting information

Tags: node.js, gps, serial-port, uart, at-command

To be as concise as possible, I am connecting to a telit ME910c1-nv socket modem made by multitech. It's not really relevant but I know someone will think this issue is hardware related when it's not.

The device has both a 4g cat m-1 modem and a gps module built in. I connect to these over UART to a raspberry pi.

The issue is that when I send AT commands to get the GPS location, eventually the module will stop sending and/or my code can no longer read from the serial port.

I am using node js to communicate with the module but I have also had the same issue with python. I have no issues in C though, which makes me think it is a higher level programming issue and timing issue.

An basic example is:

```
getGpsData=(modem, callback)=>{
   modem.write("AT$GPSACP\r");
   const timer = setTimeout( ()=>{
     callback(null);   
   }, 5000); //wait 5 sec before returning null
   modem.on('readable', readRaw=()=>{
     let data = modem.read();
     let output = "";
     if(data){
       data = data.toString();
       output += data;
       if(data.includes(escape_character)){ //escape character is "OK" or "ERROR"
         clearTimeout(timer);
         callback(output);
       }
     }
   });
}

//connect to serial port
modem = new serialport("/dev/serial0");
on.('connect', ()=>{
//on connect read gps data at constant interval
   setInterval(()=>{
     getGpsData(modem, (data)=>{
        modem.removeListener('readable', rawRead);
        console.log(data); 
     }
   }, 10000); //loop every 10 sec
});
```

When I run this, I will get about 10 - 20 gps readings and then all nulls. When I stop my code and start it again, it works fine. Sometimes it runs for an hour or more without any issues and then starts producing nulls and never recovers. If I connect directly to the modem and send it AT commands, I don't get this issue at all. It's as if my reads are out of sync with what the module it writing to the serial port.

The output from the module comes as:

```
$gpsacp: "gpsdata..........."

OK
```

I get null data reads because it times out and my escape character is never read. Sometimes I'll get the "OK" escape character and null data also. 
I've rewritten my command and read function multiple times but always suffer the same issue. Anyone have any idea why this is happening or had similar experience?

Comment: A question in case you still need help on this topic. How are you sure that the module is still "alive"?